# Case statement for class fails, converting to string succeeds

Tags: ruby

Using `case`/`when` statements for checking an instance's class fails. If I compare an `Answer` instance's class as follows, it fails:

```
subject = Answer.new
case subject.class
when Answer  
  true
else  
  false
end  
# => false
```

If I convert an `Answer` instance's class to string, it works:

```
subject = Answer.new
case subject.class.to_s
when 'Answer'  
  true
else  
  false
end  
# => true
```

This isn't how it's supposed to be, right? Additionally, when I run a simple comparison, it works:

```
subject.class == Answer
# => true
```

---

Edit: Using the newly-learned properties of Ruby's `case` and `===`, this code is valid and works.

```
subject = Answer.new
case subject
when Answer  
  true
else  
  false
end  
# => true
```

Comment: The Ruby `case` statement is based upon the `===` operator. Google search "ruby triple equal case statement" and you'll find some interesting information which will explain your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` in Ruby is based upon the `===` operator. When you have:

```
case x
when foo
...
when bar
...
end
```

It's behavior is:

```
if foo === x
   ...
elsif bar === x
   ...
end
```

In a general sense, `a === b` means that *`b` belongs to or is subsumed by what `a` represents*. See the definition given [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D):

> Case Equality—Returns true if obj is an instance of mod or one of
>   mod’s descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in case
>   statements to classify objects by class.

For example, `(2..7) === 3` is true because 3 is contained in the range, `2..7`. Based upon how objects define `===`, it is also true that `2 === 2` Since `2` belongs to the class of `2`. It's *not a commutative operator* (for example, `a === b` true doesn't mean `b === a` is true). An expression such as `Integer === 3` is `true` because a `3` is an `Integer`. But it is not true that `3 === Integer` because `3` doesn't represent or subsume the entire class of `Integer`. So the `===` operator makes the Ruby `case` statement do some powerful and useful matching.

In this particular `case` statement, you're checking if `Answer === subject.class` is true. The operator `===` is not defined on a class object in such a way as to make this `true` because `subject.class` does not belong to the class of `Answer`. However, `s.class == Answer` is `true` because `s.class` is indeed `Answer`. So the case doesn't match. However, `Answer === s` is true because `s` is a type of `Answer`.

Comment: Enhance your answer with a link to documentation and some excerpt from it (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the link. I shall do that.

Comment: Had no idea about the `===`. However, shouln't the `case` statement then, instead of compiling to `foo === x` be compiled to `x === foo` (which, as I gather, would make it true in my use)? Or is there an advanced use of `case` which takes into account the specifics of `===`?

Comment: @KristapsA. nope. See the details in my answer. `===` is not commutative. `x === foo` would mean `foo` belongs to the class of `x`, which may or may not be true. For example, `Integer === 3` is true, but `3 === Integer` is false (`3` does not subsume all of `Integer`, just one integer).

Comment: Ah. Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

`Answer` returns the generic class definition.
`Answer.new.class` returns a hash of an actual instance.

```
> Answer
 => Answer(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
> Answer.new
 => #<Answer id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Notice the `#` and the different formatting.

As **lurker** kindly pointed out in his answer, `case` uses the `===` operator, not `==`.

Using this information, you can rewrite your case statement like this

```
 > subject = Answer.new
 > case subject      
?>   when Answer
?>   true
?>   else
?>     false
?>   end
 => true
```

The above `case` translates to "does `subject` belong to `Answer`?". And the answer is yes, because `subject` is an instance of `Answer`.

Comment: This is the same as the string method though, isn't it? I mean, the `.class` method of an Answer instance still returns `Answer` (see last code block of my question), except in a `case` statement. I could use the names instead, but I feel like it shouldn't be necessary just to check if a class is the class.

Comment: Sorry but in the last code block in my question, Ruby confirms that `subject.class == Answer` is true — so why is it true in a condition but not in a `case` statement which should check the same condition?

Comment: @KristapsA.: "which should check the same condition" - that's a wrong expectation. `case/when` is not a simple replacement for `if/==`. It's a completely different beast. See @lurker's answer.

Comment: @Kristaps A.: I have updated my answer with a better explanation of what's happening.